# Ошибка при передачи параметра даты в базу данных

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

Мне необходимо передать в качестве параметра сравнения дату. Благодаря этому на экран выводятся соответствующие данные. Запрос к базе данных возникает, когда меняется значение dateTimePicker1, однако, когда я пытаюсь лично ввести значение dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now - мне выдает ошибку `"Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."`

```
    public Form()
        }
          ...
          dateTimerPicker1.Value = DateTime.Now; // Error
          ...
        }

    private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            UpdateProcedures((sender as DateTimePicker));
        }
    private void UpdateProcedures(DateTimePicker _date)
        {
            if (amount_users > 0)
            {
                string query = String.Format("SELECT p_time, p_count, p_what, p_same_what FROM Plans WHERE for_who = '{0}' " +
                    "AND ? >= p_from_date AND ? <= p_to_date", label1.Text);

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT1", _date.Value); // 25.06.2019 10:59:41 // Дата, когда ставлю Now
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT2", _date.Value); // 25.06.2019 10:59:56 // Дата, выбранная на dateTimePicker1

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                ...
        }
```

Comment: Доведите использование параметров до конца: замените подстановку `label1.Text` в `'{0}'` тоже на параметр.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) - ознакомьтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
Вместо `_date.Value` стал писать `_date.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`

Comment: Какой тип у колонок `p_from_date`, `p_to_date`? Полагаю, проще использовать `_date.Value.Date` - это уберёт время.